# Выровнять текст на экране по правому краю

Tags: c, строки, выравнивание

Текст записан одной длинной строкой. Выровнять текст на экране 
по правому краю, так что бы в каждой строке было 60 символов и 
каждая строка заканчивалась знаком препинания или пробелом. 
Помогите, как решить?

Comment: Выравнивание по правому краю - правый край ровный, левый как получится. Если нужны оба края ровные - это выравнивание по ширине. Та какое именно выравнивание нужно? Ну и добавьте в вопрос свои попытки решить задачу, а то можно подумать, что вы просите решить ее за вас

Comment: @rdorn по ширине, нужно вставлять пробелы, равномерно между словами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условия задания, то решение может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const size_t N = 60;
    char s[] = "There are a few lingering questions on HTTPS "
               "we're not confident in until we do it live."
               " One of these is the Google site move in webmasters."
               " It still (to our disbelief) treats HTTP and HTTPS as "
               "different properties. I have no idea why. "
               "And the \"change of address\" tool doesn't support such "
               "a move either.";

    const char *p = s;
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    while ( n )
    {
        size_t i = n < N ? n : N;

        while ( isalnum( ( unsigned char )p[i] ) && i != 0 ) --i;

        if ( i == 0 ) i = n < N ? n : N;

        printf( "%*.*s\n", ( int )N, ( int )i, p );

        n -= i;
        p += i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль.

```
      There are a few lingering questions on HTTPS we're not
       confident in until we do it live. One of these is the
 Google site move in webmasters. It still (to our disbelief)
    treats HTTP and HTTPS as different properties. I have no
  idea why. And the "change of address" tool doesn't support
                                         such a move either.
```